# Find volume between plane $z=3-2y$ and paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having problems finding the volume of the finite region enclosed by the plane

$$z=3-2y$$

and the paraboloid 
$$z=x^2+y^2$$

I found their intersection:

$$x^2+(y+1)^2=4$$

which means they intersect in a circle?

I know we can treat the finite region, say E, as the set of $(x,y)$ belonging to region D (projection onto x-y plane) where z varies between two functions.

I just don't know what the region D is?

When  I type in the paraboloid and the plane into Geogebra, I find that they intersect in  a circle, but what is the region D?

Please help -  I have been stumped for days.

Comment: Now that you have the intersection, can you change to polar coordinates and find the bounds for $z$, $\theta$ and $r$?

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to introduce the variable changes $u=x$ and $v=y+1$. Then, the two surfaces become,

$$z=5-2v,\>\>\>\>\>z=u^2+(v-1)^2$$

and the integration is over the circle centered at the origin $u^2+v^2=4$. The volume integral is then,

$$V=\int_{u,v}[5-2v - u^2-(v-1)^2]dudv = \int_{u,v}(4-u^2-v^2)dudv$$

Convert it to the polar coordinates to integrate,

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 (4-r^2)rdrd\theta=8\pi$$